# Python numpy array sum over certain indices

Tags: python, numpy, sum, indices

How to perform a sum just for a list of indices over numpy array, e.g., if I have an array `a = [1,2,3,4]` and a list of indices to sum, `indices = [0, 2]` and I want a fast operation to give me the answer `4` because the value for summing value at index 0 and index 2 in `a` is `4`

Comment: `a[indices].sum()`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `sum` directly after indexing with `indices`:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
indices = [0, 2] 
a[indices].sum()
```

Answer (score 13):

The accepted `a[indices].sum()` approach copies data and creates a new array, which might cause problem if the array is large. `np.sum` actually has an argument to mask out colums, you can just do

```py
np.sum(a, where=[True, False, True, False])
```

Which doesn't copy any data.

The mask array can be obtained by:

```py
mask = np.full(4, False)
mask[np.array([0,2])] = True
```

Comment: Since the question asks for a fast operation, this is the better answer IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> indices = [0, 2]
>>> sum(a[i] for i in indices)
4
```

#### Faster

If you have a lot of numbers and you want high speed, then you need to use numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> a[indices]
array([1, 3])
>>> np.sum(a[indices])
4
```