# Numpy python sum over vectors of different indices

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix, sum

I have the following formula:

[image]

that i have to code (C is a mtrix, y and y_star are vectors). I tried the following, according to this post: [Python numpy array sum over certain indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734392/python-numpy-array-sum-over-certain-indices)

```
> def chisq02(y, y_star, C_inv):
>     indices = len(y)
>     return np.sum(np.sum(np.matmul(y[i] - y_star[i], np.matmul(C_inv, y[j]-y_star[j])) for i in indices)for j in indices)
```

but it returns me the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Obviously it does not work... Does anyone know how this could work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrices/vectors are not arrays, first convert them to arrays:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array(y)
y_star = np.array(y_star)
C_inv = np.array(C_inv)
```

Use this, no need for loops:

```
def chisq02(y, y_star, C_inv):
    return np.sum(np.matmul(np.matmul(y-y_star, C_inv), (y-y_star)))
```

If your `y` and `y_star` are vectors, simply this will work:

```
def chisq02(y, y_star, C_inv):
    return np.matmul(np.matmul(y-y_star, C_inv), (y-y_star))
```

Comment: But i need to sum two times. Are you sure that this is equivalent to 2 sums ?

Comment: @user11659631 Always try with a sample toy to check. `np.sum` sums all elements by default: checkout numpy doc https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html: _The default, axis=None, will sum all of the elements of the input array._

Comment: @user11659631 in fact, you dont even need sum. just remove it.

Comment: I am so confused, why don't I need to sum ?:/

Comment: Bacause the matrix multiplication `np.matmul` has the sum inside it. When you multiply matrices, you multiply rows by columns and then sum. That is the whole point of using numpy and matrix multiplication. looping with numpy is discouraged and generally not a good idea. If you have lists convert them to numpy first. I will add the edit to post for it.

Comment: And matrix multiplication always start from the rigth to the left so should it be  np.matmul(y-y_star, np.matmul(C_inv, y-y_star))

Comment: Ok i see I think i need to think that trough ! Thank you !

Comment: matrix multiplication has associative property, it does not matter which you do first: A(BC) = (AB)C

Answer (score 2):

Your `indices` variable is just an integer, the length of `y`. But it must be a list from 0 to `len(y)` to loop over all indices. You can do this like so:

```py
indices_list = range(len(y))
```

The `range()` function produces a list `[0, 1, ..., len(y)-1]`. Then you can loop over this list in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

`indices = len(y)` returns you an integer, so to iterate you need to use `for i in range(indices)`.

I suspect you don't need to use `np.matmul` in your case because you do scalar multiplication according to your formula. I suppose `C_inv[i][j]` should be used instead of `C_inv`.

Comment: Yes i think you're right ! I tried this, and it didn't return me an error: np.sum( np.sum(y[i] - y_star[i]* C_inv[i][j]* y[j]-y_star[j] for i in indices)for j in indices)