# Python numpy 2D array sum over certain indices

Tags: python, numpy

There is a 2-d array like this:

```
img = [
  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
  [[2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 3], [6, 7, 6]],
  [[9, 8, 1], [9, 8, 3], [9, 8, 5]]
]
```

And i just want to get the sum of certain indices which are like this:

```
indices = [[0, 0], [0, 1]] # which means img[0][0] and img[0][1]
# means here is represents
```

There was a similar ask about 1-d array in stackoverflow in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734392/python-numpy-array-sum-over-certain-indices), but it got a error when I tried to use `print(img[indices])`. Because I want to make it clear that the element of `img` are those which indicates by indices, and then get the  <del>mean</del>  sum of it.

**Expected output**

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Just to be cleared, when you sum [0,0] and [0,1], the result would be [5, 7, 9], or total 5 +7 + 9 = 21?

Comment: the result would be `[5, 7, 9]`

Comment: Can you provide an example that uses actual arrays, not lists, shows the expected output, and indices that aren't transposeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.array(img)
img[tuple(indices)].sum(axis = 0)
#array([5, 7, 9])
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist why?

Comment: I am sorry to say that i did not clear that `img[0][0] + img[0][1]` should be `[5, 7, 9]`, so in this answer i got the right answer when i changed the `axis = 1` to `axis = 0`.

Comment: @luneice edited. by the way, you want the sum or the mean?

Comment: He want the sum basically. The comment is quite confuse "# which means image[0][0] and image[0][1]", `means` here is `represents`

Comment: Also, you want to transpose the indices most likely

Comment: i want to sum of it.

Comment: yes, In comment `# which means image[0][0] and image[0][1]`, the word `means` here is `represents`

Comment: @TấnNguyên I was talking about the text above that

Comment: @MadPhysicist I still don't get why you say this is not quite right

Comment: I'm pretty sure the index is transposed, but the question is actually pretty ambiguous, so you might be right

Answer (score 1):

When you supply a fancy index, each element of the index tuple represents a different axis. The shape of the index arrays broadcasts to the shape of the output you get.

In your case, the rows of `indices.T` are the indices in each axis. You can convert them into an index tuple and append `slice(None)`, which is the programmatic equivalent of `:`. You can take the mean of the resulting 2D array directly:

```
img[tuple(indices.T) + (slice(None),)].sum(0)
```

Another way is to use the splat operator:

```
img[(*indices.T, slice(None))].sum(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the result would be [5, 7, 9] which is sum over the column of the list. Then easy:

```
img = np.asarray(img)
indices = [[0, 0], [0, 1]]
img[(indices)].sum(axis = 0)
```

Result:

```
array([5, 7, 9])
```