# How to get all pixs by certain indices from a image array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The image array shape is `(540, 960, 3)`, and it like this:

```
img_rgb = [[[ 95  71  71]
  [ 95  71  71]
  [ 95  71  71]
  ...
  [182 171 181]
  [182 171 181]
  [182 171 181]]

 [[ 95  71  70]
  [ 95  71  70]
  [ 95  71  71]
  ...
  [183 172 182]
  [183 172 182]
  [183 172 182]]

 [[ 95  72  70]
  [ 95  71  70]
  [ 95  71  71]
  ...
  [183 172 182]
  [183 172 182]
  [183 172 182]]

 ...

 [[ 36  35  45]
  [ 36  35  45]
  [ 36  35  45]
  ...
  [ 49  45  50]
  [ 49  45  50]
  [ 49  45  50]]

 [[ 36  35  45]
  [ 36  35  45]
  [ 36  35  45]
  ...
  [ 49  45  50]
  [ 49  45  50]
  [ 49  45  50]]

 [[ 36  35  45]
  [ 36  35  45]
  [ 36  35  45]
  ...
  [ 49  45  50]
  [ 49  45  50]
  [ 49  45  50]]]
```

And I want to get elements by `indices` that indicate the each element index, and the `indices` like this:

```
indices = [
 [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]
]
```

**Expected output**

```
[
  [ 95  71  71],
  [ 95  71  71],
  [ 95  71  71],
]
```

There are tow similar question in those link, one is [Python numpy 2D array sum over certain indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65768227/python-numpy-2d-array-sum-over-certain-indices), and another is [Finding the (x,y) indexes of specific (R,G,B) color values from images stored in NumPy ndarrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138339/finding-the-x-y-indexes-of-specific-r-g-b-color-values-from-images-stored-in).

It got a `IndexError: too many indices for array` When I tried question one by `img_rgb[tuple(indices)]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indexing numpy array with another numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508352/indexing-numpy-array-with-another-numpy-array) - you'd need to transpose though: `img_rgb[tuple(np.array(indices).T)]`

Comment: @DanielF or `img_rgb[tuple(zip(*indices))]`

Comment: Thanks, `img_rgb[tuple(np.array(indices).T)]` works.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to transpose `indices`.

```
img_rgb[tuple(np.transpose(indices))]
```

`np.tranpose()` would work even if `indices` is just a list, since it expects as input any "array-like" structure.

Comment: This is not quite right, the output result shape is `(2, 3, 960, 3)`, the shape should be `(3, 3)`.

Comment: @luneice - Sorry about that. Edited now.

Comment: Woops, didn't see you'd fixed it before I duped it.